# How to increase integer value </aura:iteration> In lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:attribute name="opl" type="OpportunityLineItem[]"/>

 <aura:attribute name="rowCnt" type="Integer" default="1" />

 <aura:iteration items="{!v.opl}" var="item">

            <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-EXT_PRODUCT_ID['+(v.rowCnt)+']'}" value='{!item.Test_Sku__c}'/>
            <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD13['+(v.rowCnt)+']'}" value='{!item.Test_PartNo__c}'/>
            <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY['+(v.rowCnt)+']'}" value='{!item.Test_Quantity__c}'/>
            <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-PRICE1['+(v.rowCnt)+']'}" value='{!item.Test_UnitPrice__c}'/>
            <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD12['+(v.rowCnt)+']'}" value='{!item.Sort_Order__c}'/>


  </aura:iteration>


OpportunityLineItem have five records are there each and evary time 
increase the values 

like:
First time

 <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-EXT_PRODUCT_ID['1]'}" value='{!item.Test_Sku__c}'/>
            <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD13['1']'}" value='{!item.Test_PartNo__c}'/>
            <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY['1']}" value='{!item.Test_Quantity__c}'/>
            <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-PRICE1['1']}" value='{!item.Test_UnitPrice__c}'/>
            <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD12['1']'}" value='{!item.Sort_Order__c}'/>
```

second time

```
 <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-EXT_PRODUCT_ID['2]'}" value='{!item.Test_Sku__c}'/>
        <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD13['2']'}" value='{!item.Test_PartNo__c}'/>
        <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY['2']}" value='{!item.Test_Quantity__c}'/>
        <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-PRICE1['2']}" value='{!item.Test_UnitPrice__c}'/>
        <input type="text" name="{!'NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD12['2']'}" value='{!item.Sort_Order__c}'/>
```

please help me

Answer (score 3):

`aura:iteration` has an attribute for this purpose: indexVar.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.opl}" var="item" indexVar="index">
  ... {!index}
```

Do not try to modify an attribute during rendering. Fun and excitement await those who try.

Comment: thank for your quick reply

Comment: How to pass the index value in iteration input name

Comment: @Ramya It's just the name of the variable without any prefix like `c` or `v`.

Comment: Can we convert the indexVar to integer , so as to use `<aura:renderIf isTrue="{!lessthan(index,4)}}">`

Comment: @sfdcfox  Is it possible to show {!index} in descending order?